# Java Programming ,Command Prompt

Tags: java, command-prompt

I am trying to compile multiple .jar libraries from command prompt but I keep getting this error:

```
C:\Users\welcome\Documents\NetBeansProjects\LearningJAVA\JavaApplication8\src\javaapplication8>java -version
java version "1.7.0"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0-b147)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 21.0-b17, mixed mode)

C:\Users\welcome\Documents\NetBeansProjects\LearningJAVA\JavaApplication8\src\javaapplication8>cd C:
\Users\welcome\Documents\NetBeansProjects\LearningJAVA\JavaApplication8\src\javaapplication8

C:\Users\welcome\Documents\NetBeansProjects\LearningJAVA\JavaApplication8\src\javaapplication8>javac
 -cp *; JavaApplication8.java

C:\Users\welcome\Documents\NetBeansProjects\LearningJAVA\JavaApplication8\src\javaapplication8>java
JavaApplication8
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: JavaApplication8 (wrong name: javaapplica
tion8/JavaApplication8)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(Unknown Source)
```

How can I solve it?

Comment: What is the package name at the top of `JavaApplications8.java`?

Answer (score 1):

Your are passing the wrong argument to `-cp`,

```
javac -cp *; JavaApplication8.java
```

The asterisk (`*`) is [globbed](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glob_%28programming%29) to filenames in the current directory before `javac` runs, I'm fairly certain you wanted -

```
javac -cp . JavaApplication8.java
```

**Edit**

Based on your comment, go to the parent directory and type

```
java -cp .;jarfile1.jar;jarfile2.jar javaapplication8.JavaApplication8
```

Comment: I have all the -jar files and my java file in the same directory. With the javac cammand the class file is generated but when I try to run it using the        java JavaApplication8                command I keep getting the same above mentioned error. The same error appears when I try to run a single file with no external libraries.

Comment: @user3683877 `java -cp .;jarfile1.jar;jarfile2.jar JavaApplication8` (If I follow your second question, and you're on windows; on *nixes you use ':' to separate jars in a classpath)

Comment: Again I got the same error

Comment: What is the package of your application? You need to specify that as well.

Answer (score 0):

You don't compile .jar files. you have to run them;
try this:

```
java -jar filename1.jar filename2.jar
```

Comment: Yeah but I need to add them to the classpath for my java file JavaApplication8.java . I can generate the .class file with the javac command but when I try to run it using "java javaApplication8"     I run into problems. The same error pops out when I run single class file with no external libraries.